# Select2 customize rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using the jQuery select2 library and have tags enabled so that I can dynamically add options to the dropdown list. However, I would like to customize what the tag option looks like so that it is clear that choosing it will add the option. This is my setup:

```
$field.select2({ 
  data: response,
  tags: true,
});
```

Currently it renders like this:

[image]

But I would like it to render something like this:

[image]

I tried playing around with the createTag property but wasn't able to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Set configuration options `templateResult` (how options appear in the dropdown) and `templateSelection` (how the selected option is rendered).  Both of these are callbacks so the value will be a function.

Here's the example shown in the [Dropdown section](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating) of the docs:

```
function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }
  var baseUrl = "/user/pages/images/flags";
  var $state = $(
    '<span><img src="' + baseUrl + '/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
  );
  return $state;
};

$(".js-example-templating").select2({
  templateResult: formatState
});
```

See also the [configuration API](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api) for an overview of the configuration options.

Comment: I should have been more clear, but I don't want all options to have custom rendering applied to it, I just want the "tag" option to have custom rendering.

Comment: @Andrew What you can do in your `templateResult` method is conditionally apply styling only when the option is a new `tag`.

Comment: Do you know what that conditional would be? I couldn’t figure that out

Comment: @Andrew  Yes.  The condition would be if the typed tag text doesn't already exist as an option in the select.

Comment: The suggestion by @user9263373 is correct. The function will be passed an object with `id` and `text` properties. If `id` is not an existing option then `return "+ Add " + obj.text;` otherwise `return obj.text;`.  If you're doing an ajax lookup you'll need some chicanery on the back end and the front end, and in this case I suggest skipping the effort and setting your placeholder text to "Select an existing or type a new option".

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Paul's answer, here's a *mostly* complete working example for you using the `tags` and `templateResult` options.  It conditionally apply formatting when the typed text is a new tag (wasn't part of the original select options).

**UPDATE**

It turns out you're correct that `templateSelection` isn't the answer since the `+` sign only appears when the dropdown is displayed and that's in the `templateResult` callback.  So the answer was to make `templateResult` more robust with a few extra conditions.  The idea is track a new tag by saving it in a variable called `recentlySelected`.  This way when the dropdown renders, if the value matches `recentlySelected`, then don't display the `+` sign.  Working example is updated.  This modification makes it a fully complete answer.

```js
// Populate an array of initial options.
var options = $("#field option").map(function(){
  return this.value.toLowerCase();
}).get();
var recentlySelected = '';

// Create select2
$("#field").select2({
  tags: true,
  templateResult: formatTag
});

// formatTag to conditionally applies formatting
function formatTag(filteredOption) {

  if (recentlySelected.toLowerCase() === filteredOption.text.toLowerCase()) {
    return filteredOption.text;
  }

  if (options.indexOf(filteredOption.text.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
    // Typed text wasn't an original option, prepend with '+' sign.
    if (filteredOption.text !== 'Searching…') {
      recentlySelected = filteredOption.text;
    }
    return '+ ' + filteredOption.text; 
  }

  return filteredOption.text;

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>

<select id="field">
  <option value="First Option">First Option</option>
  <option value="Second Option">Second Option</option>
  <option value="Third Option">Third Option</option>
  <option value="Fourth Option">Fourth Option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is very close to working. Now the suggestion box correctly has the '+' in it, but the problem is if I press enter to add the tag, it now continues to appear with the '+' in the dropdown. Any idea on a fix?

Comment: @Andrew that's why I said it's mostly complete :)  I figured this was enough to get you started and you can pick up from there.  Next steps would be to code the `templateSelection` option and write a similar function that undoes `templateResult` by stripping off the `+` sign.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks your suggestion was helpful! But I don't think that templateSelection will help me here since the problem is that it shows up in the option list incorrectly (rather than showing up incorrectly as a selection). I've been working on this for a while and may need to do something hacky with jQuery because i'm not sure that there's a clean solution for this using the library.